# How can I know the total number of chunks/items to be processed at the beginning of a Spring Batch Step?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am trying to get fancy with my batch jobs and utilize a progress bar for my batch jobs, like the one here: https://github.com/ctongfei/progressbar

To accurately populate a progress bar like the one linked above, however, I would need to know the total number of chunks/elements to be processed in the job.

I am looking to add this in my ChunkListener. Within here, I am able to grab my count of items read -> processed -> written thru the ChunkContext:

```
context.getStepContext().getStepExecution().getWriteCount()
```

What I cannot figure out, however, is how to get the total number of chunks or total number of items in the step, while the step is in progress. Does Spring Batch have this capability? If so, how do I get this value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spring Batch does not provide this capability as it heavily depends on the input data. You need to calculate the total number of records upfront and use that information to calculate the progress during the step execution.

Calculating the total number of records can be done using a job/step listener or a tasklet for example which puts the information in the execution context. Then, an  `ItemReadListener` can be used to calculate the progress based on the current item count and the total item count.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `StepExecutionListener's beforeStep` method to calculate total number of items to be processed. Divide that value with the `CHUNK SIZE` any you will get how many chunks will be processed.